# EmberJS - hasMany Fixtures Model Empty Value

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have 3 different fixture models, as shown below.

```
var Room = DS.Model.extend({
       title: DS.attr('string'),
       categories: DS.hasMany('Category', { async: true }),
       isSelected: DS.attr('boolean')
});
var Category = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    room: DS.belongsTo('Room', {async: true }),
    materials: DS.hasMany('Material', { async: true }),
    isSelected: DS.attr('boolean')
});
var Material = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    category: DS.belongsTo('Category', {async: true} ),
    isSelected: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

I find when I try to view the contents inside the Materials model it is blank. In my controller I expose the materials by doing this:

```
currentMaterials: function() {
  var room = this.filterBy('isSelected', true).get('firstObject');
  var categories = room.get('categories');
  var selectedCategory = categories.get('firstObject');
  var material = selectedCategory.get('materials');
  return material;

}.property('@each.isSelected')
```

However when I try to access currentMaterials the value is null. I am ONLY able to access its values if I first access the Rooms/Categories using a {{#each} loop. Oddly once I do the {{#each}} I am then able to access the values in currentMaterials.

Does anyone understand why?

Answer (score 1):

It's due to fact of promises existance. Your `categories` relationship is async, which means that it's not present initially and ember-data should fetch it if needed. However, it takes time to fetch data, therefore ember-data returns a promise from this: `var categories = room.get('categories')`. After that promise, you first get `firstObject` from it, which does not exist for a promise (is null), and than you get `materials` relationship from that null. It simply is null.

However, ember templates are smart and if you put an `each` on them, they know that these relationships are needed and makes ember-data fetch these data.

What you can do? If you need this data to perform page-specific job, you should make sure that you have access to it before showing the page to the user - therefore in the model hook. You can use Ember.RSVP to make multiple fetch calls and set them up in the controller:

```
model: function() {
  data =
    room: store.find("room")
    categories: store.find("category)
    materials: store.find("material")

  return Ember.RSVP.hash(data)
}
```

However, take notice that it will fetch `all` the materials, etc. If you need only the ones connected to your model, you should consider speeding up your data fetching using [side loading](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/the-rest-adapter/). If you are using fixtures, it won't work.

Last that I can think of is making computed property a method that would fetch the data, but set them on other variable. You can use some kind of flag to inform the app when the data is ready:

```
currentMaterials: function() {
  var room = this.filterBy('isSelected', true).get('firstObject');
  room.get('categories').then(function(categories) {
    return categories.get('firstObject').get('materials');
  }).then(function(materials) {
    // here you have your materials
    // you can pass _this to that method and set these materials
    // on some kind of controller property (e.g. materialsChosen)
    // and use a flag like setting 'is Fetching' on the start of this
    // computed property and setting down right here
  });
}.property('@each.isSelected')
```

Comment: Excellent Explanation to describe a very complex configuration. Thanks for your help Jakub